# How to blit 72 images efficiently

Tags: python, pygame

```
def check_mx_range1(mx, my):
        switch1 = 0 
        while switch1==0:
            for mx_range1 in mousedata.mx_ranges1:
                    if mx_range1[0] < mx < mx_range1[1] and 890 < my < 920 and switch1==0:
                        switch1+=1
                        a11=0
                        b11=0
                        a11=str(mx_range1[2])
                        b11=str(mx_range1[3])
                        mousedata.dic_n[a11]+=1
                        #print(mx_range1)
                        #print(a11)
                        #print(b11)
                        print(mousedata.dic_n[a11])
                        return True
                    if False:
                        break
            return False
```

It might be hard to articulate this... Okay so I'm making "drunkopoly", so these functions call an array of ranges and puts them into a dictionary.

The dictionaries are as follows:

```
dic_s={'101': [868.0, 905.0], '102': [827.0, 905.0], '103': [785.0, 905.0], '104': [743.0, 905.0], '105': [701.0, 905.0], '106': [659.0, 905.0], '107': [617.0, 905.0], '108': [575.0, 905.0], '109': [533.0, 905.0], '110': [491.0, 905.0], '111': [449.0, 905.0], '112': [407.0, 905.0], '113': [365.0, 905.0], '114': [323.0, 905.0], '115': [281.0, 905.0], '116': [239.0, 905.0], '117': [197.0, 905.0], '118': [155.0, 905.0]}
dic_n={'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0, '9': 0, '10': 0, '11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, '20': 0, '21': 0, '22': 0, '23': 0, '24': 0, '25': 0, '26': 0, '27': 0, '28': 0, '29': 0, '30': 0, '31': 0, '32': 0, '33': 0, '34': 0, '35': 0, '36': 0, '37': 0, '38': 0, '39': 0, '40': 0, '41': 0, '42': 0, '43': 0, '44': 0, '45': 0, '46': 0, '47': 0, '48': 0, '49': 0, '50': 0, '51': 0, '52': 0, '53': 0, '54': 0, '55': 0, '56': 0, '57': 0, '58': 0, '59': 0, '60': 0, '61': 0, '62': 0, '63': 0, '64': 0, '65': 0, '66': 0, '67': 0, '68': 0, '69': 0, '70': 0, '71': 0, '72': 0}
```

dic_s pertains to the locations of 18 surfaces, although it should really be 72 and dic_n pertains to the number of times that area has been clicked.

Now the main code that runs the number counter is:

```
def run_game():

    pygame.init()
    #Font information
    gamefont=pygame.freetype.Font("OpenSans-Bold.ttf",12)
    #Number in font mx and my posion of mouse curser
    gamestage=0
    n=0
    text_surface, rect = gamefont.render("0",(4, 8, 18))
    text_surface1, rect = gamefont.render("0",(4, 8, 18))
    #Main screen display options
    ai_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Drunkopoly")

    b=screen.blit(board,(0,0))
    #Beggining of the main game loop

    while True:
        #keyboard and mouse events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if gamestage == 0 and gamestage <= 1:
                gamestage += 1
                mx, my =pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(mx,my)

                mousedata.check_mx_range1(mx,my)

                    pygame.display.flip()


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if gamestage != 0:
                gamestage = 0


        screen.blit(text_surface, (mousedata.dic_s['101'])) 

        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

So that means that I would need 72 surfaces with numbers. How might I approach this? It seems like pygame might not be able to handle 72 images being thrown at it.

keep in mind this is my first week although I've been spending 12 hours a day coding haha. So if part of the code is bad let me know, and there is stuff I can change on both style and approach also let me know, general advice is also welcome.

I was able to get a counter working for one but for all of them it might be too hard.

```
                dic_n['1']
                text_surface, rect = gamefont.render(n,(4, 8, 18))
                screen.blit(board,(0,0))
                pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blitting 72 surfaces is not a problem.

Here's an example of moving and blitting 72 surfaces. Nothing is optimized, and it still runs with several hundreds FPS:

```
import pygame
import random

class Stuff(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(random.randint(-1, 1), random.randint(-1, 1))

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 26)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for _ in range(72):
        x, y = random.randint(0, 500), random.randint(0, 500)
        color = random.choice(['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white', 'orange'])
        sprites.add(Stuff((x, y), pygame.Color(color)))

    dt = 1
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites.update()
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        text = font.render(f'{clock.get_fps()} FPS', True, pygame.Color('black'))
        screen.blit(text, (20, 20))
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(20000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

---

As for clicking the different surfaces, you should each surface give a state that counts the clicks, so let's keep using the `Sprite` class, and things become easy:

```
import pygame
import random

class Stuff(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, color, font):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.image.blit(font.render('0', True, (0, 0, 0)), (10, 10))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.font = font
        self.hits = 0
        self.color = color

    def update(self, events):
        self.rect.move_ip(random.randint(-1, 1), random.randint(-1, 1))
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    self.hits += 1
                    self.image.fill(self.color)
                    self.image.blit(self.font.render(f'{self.hits}', True, (0, 0, 0)), (10, 10))

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 26)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    dic_s={'101': [868.0, 905.0], '102': [827.0, 905.0], '103': [785.0, 905.0], '104': [743.0, 905.0], '105': [701.0, 905.0], '106': [659.0, 905.0], '107': [617.0, 905.0], '108': [575.0, 905.0], '109': [533.0, 905.0], '110': [491.0, 905.0], '111': [449.0, 905.0], '112': [407.0, 905.0], '113': [365.0, 905.0], '114': [323.0, 905.0], '115': [281.0, 905.0], '116': [239.0, 905.0], '117': [197.0, 905.0], '118': [155.0, 905.0]}

    for key in dic_s:
        color = random.choice(['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white', 'orange'])
        sprites.add(Stuff(dic_s[key], pygame.Color(color), font))

    dt = 1
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites.update(events)
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        text = font.render(f'{clock.get_fps()} FPS', True, pygame.Color('black'))
        screen.blit(text, (20, 20))
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]